# irresponsible behavior?

Tags: support

[How do Dvaitins explain Vedic verses which declare deities other than Narayana to be supreme?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26847/how-do-dvaitins-explain-vedic-verses-which-declare-deities-other-than-narayana-t)

Moderators - these two are speculating about people's private information - they may be exposing the site to legal liability.

Comment: First Meta post against me. 

Answer (score 4):

First of all, let me explain others what User S K means in this post. The thing is  User Anubhav Jha and me were speculating on what Quora a/c belongs to S K in the comments (now deleted) of that post which made S K create this post.

Since, I'm the person involved in this, I apologise. I know I shouldn't have speculated your Quora a/c. Even though, I'm not entirely sure whether speculating one's Quora a/c is same as speculating somebody's private information, I regret asking User Anubhav Jha. If I have violated any rule of the Stack Exchange community, I'm ready to accept any punishment.

Thank you.

Comment: To help clarify matters to you _ SE allows users to retain their anonymity. Having an account on a site like quora that forces people to use their real identities does not license users of SE to strip other users of their anonymity. If people wanted to advertise their real name or quora account details, they may do so voluntarily but the rest of us don't have the right to do so. It is doxing which is a crime.

Answer (score 1):

Use flags for addressing moderators. Meta is *not* the right place.

If some issue is to be taken to the attention of moderators, you should use flags and explain what is the problem. We as a community will know nothing what happened and can do nothing if there is no context provided. Posting on meta for the attention of moderator is not the right thing to do. Meta is for bringing site issues to the community's attention. In this case, the community can do nothing. Moderators have tools with which they can look into deleted comments and take appropriate action. Posting on meta is not helpful. Moreover, it creates confusion among the users.